# encrypted links from google cloudrun svc to cloudrun svc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Backstory(but possibly can be skipped): The other day, I finished connecting to MySQL full SSL from a Cloud Run service without really doing any SSL cert stuff which was great!!!  Just click 'only allow SSL' in GCP and click 'generate server certs', allow my Cloud Run service to have access to database instance, swap out tcp socket factory with google's factory and set some props and it worked which was great!

PROBLEM:

NOW, I am trying to figure out the secure Google Cloud Run service to Cloud Run service security and reading

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service

which has us requesting a token over `HTTP`???  Why is this not over `HTTPS`?  Is communication from my Docker container to the token service actually encrypted?

Can I communicate `HTTP` to `HTTP` between two Cloud Run services and it will be encrypted?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: You confusing `one service invokes another one over HTTP using its endpoint URL`. That sentence does NOT mean not encrypted. That sentence is referring to the application protocol Hypertext Transfer Protocol which includes both http and https. Cloud Run endpoints enforce https endpoints and will redirect the caller from http to https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#is_metadata_information_secure:

> When you make a request to get information from the metadata server, your request and the subsequent metadata response never leave the physical host that is running the virtual machine instance.

The traffic from your container to the metadata server at `http://metadata/` stays entirely within your project and thus SSL is not required, there is no opportunity for it to be intercepted.

Comment: and what about service in cloud run to another service in cloud run?  If I talk over http, is it secure?  Normally, this would not be secure, but outside the container, they can run http within an SSL connection...I just don't know what google is doing internally.

Comment: the real goal is to make sure no one can view what is transmitted here even if that person is in the datacenter.  Much like once you use SSL, you can sniff all you want, but you can read the contents without the keys.

Comment: Requests between Cloud Run services must still use HTTPS. The HTTP request here is only for the metadata server which is local to the instance.